# Sharing public key certificate

Tags: open-source, visual-studio, keys

I'm working on a piece of software in Visual Studio. I created a PKCS#12 archive in Visual Studio to strong name sign my assemblies. I then extracted the public key from the archive using OpenSSL.

I realise that I must remove the PKCS#12 archive from the VS solution before making it publicly available but what do I do with the public key?

Should I bundle it with my solution or make it available for download online where my solution is hosted?

How would a user verify my assemblies with the public key?

If I remove the archive from the solution then Visual Studio will complain because it is still configured to strong name sign the solution. A third party who has obtained the source code will receive such an error when they attempt to compile it with whatever modifications they have made. Should I expect them to plug in their own key or disable it?

Comment: is your certificate self-signed?

Comment: please clarify : Why your code need explicitly **_your_** keys?

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Comment: See discussion in security exchange. It covers everything. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/how-digital-signature-verification-process-works

Comment: That post is very generic.

Comment: Cryptography is a generic concept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use public and private keys to sign, you are using what is called [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

The private key is yours. Take care to never let it leak.
The public key is, like its name, public. This is what you distribute so other people can verify if something (a code, a document, (...)) is signed by you.

The signature algorithm take the *data* and your *private key* to generate the signed data.

The verify algorithm take a *signed* data and your *public key* to verify if it was *you* that signed.

#### To verify your signed data the user will need the public key.

The signature itself will contain the public key. And the verification algorithm can verify the integrity of the contents.

#### But not the identity of the signer.

To solve this you can distribute your public key you using a [Public-key certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate). It will encapsulate your key in [X.509 structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) with a lot of information about you, and others like revocation and [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA). This will establish a relation between the public key and your personal info.

#### The Certificate Authority can say if a certificate is valid or not.

So you will need to get your certificate - generated by whatever tool - to a CA. Whey will put your certificate in their chain of trust, thus validating your certificate. [chain of trust article](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2011/09/25/ssl-who-do-you-trust/)

You will then ship your signed library to the world. The signature itself will contain everything that the checker will need to verify the signature.

#### If your certificate doesn't have a CA, only the people that have your public key will accept the signature as valid.

[image: signature_verify_flow]

Comment: I'm thinking about best practices. Do I share my public key on my website or in the folder with the binaries or in the folder with the source code?

Comment: read again. You don't do neither. The signature itself will contain your public key. Period. It's there already. The verify algoritms will use this to verify the integrity of the library. The second part is verify identity. To do it your certificate must be on a CA chain of trust.

Comment: But it's self-signed via Visual Studio.

Comment: you have a PKCS#12 right?

Comment: Yes, generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: this is used for development. Once you are ready to distribute your library you will need to go to a CA and buy a certificate. They will give you a valid pkcs#12 with you valid certificate (that will have a public key) and a valid private key. You will sign with this valid certificate and not the generated by visual studio.

Comment: No problem!  Don't forget o upvote and mark the answer as accepted if you like it... ;)