# Are all code signing certificates cross-platform?

Tags: security, distribution

I have an application, that can run on both Windows and macOS. I want to apply a digital signature to its binaries. I have already got a Thawte certificate (with private key) for Windows. Can I use the same certificate to sign my macOS `.pkg` installer?

Comment: related question about signing code : http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338007/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may be able to sign the installer with your Thawte certificate, it is sort of pointless to do so.

The whole point of signing your .pkg is so that it will be accepted by GateKeeper. Gatekeeper will only accept packages that have been signed by a certificate that Apple issues. If you want to sign for Mac OS (binaries and/or packages), you need to get a Developer Account ($99/year if you don't already have one), and use the proper certificate provided by Apple as part of the Developer program.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Apple provides two different certificates -- one for signing binaries, and one for signing installer packages. You'll need to use the right one.

Finally, if you need to build a kernel driver for MacOS (relatively rare), you need to get a kernel entitlement added to your Certificate, and sign with the kernel enabled certificate before your kext will be accepted by recent kernels.

https://developer.apple.com/contact/kext

Answer (score 0):

OS X signed applications are signed with a certificate from Apple (this is where Mac developers get their certificate from). So you may sign it with your certificate. But a user can not open it without being asked (since it's not from a certified Apple developer).